# How can i bind 2 tables with foreign key to 2 dataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have database with 2 tables: Genre and Film.

I bind Genre in dataGridView1 and Film in dataGridView2

Also I created FK in `dbo.Film`:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Film_ToGenre] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Genre] ([Id])
```

I need to choose `Genre` in `dataGridView1` and get all films with same Id in `dataGridView2` (for example I click on Thriller row and get Zodiac, Fight Club, etc)

But dataGridViews are not related, how can I do this?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                         
        SqlConnection connectionDB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\source\repos\DBWork\DBWork\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        connectionDB.Open();         
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Genre", connectionDB);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Film", connectionDB);
        DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
        DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();
        DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        BindingSource bindingSource2 = new BindingSource();

        try
        {
            dataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet1, "Genre");
            dataTable1 = dataSet1.Tables["Genre"];
            bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable1;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

            dataAdapter2.Fill(dataSet2, "Film");
            dataTable2 = dataSet2.Tables["Film"];
            bindingSource2.DataSource = dataTable2;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSource2;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connectionDB.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well... Assuming each Genre may have multiple films AND each film may belong to more than one Genre, then... this sounds like you need to “filter” the second films grid to show only films that belong to the selected Genre in the first grid. You could trigger this when the first grid’s row selection changes.

Comment: I think we can just set a many-to-one relation, that is, each film will only have one genre. But I do not understand how to realize this relation in dataGridView.

Comment: It would still be “filter.” Since you are using a `BindingSource`… with a `DataTable`, then you may need to create a `DataView` from the films table and set it as the binding sources data source. Then you could filter with something like `bindingSource2.Filter = “Genre = ‘SelectedGenreInGrid1’”. There are numerous ways you can filter the table.